# i cant see youtube videos in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium, youtube

Please help I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm new to this Operating system...when I try to see videos on You tube its just show the videos like colour Film and Ads too.I have a doubt with adobe flash player plug-in but everything is installed correctly. i have this problem In both Firefox and chromium browsers.

Answer (score 0):

type in terminal `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: You also might want to explain what the command does

Comment: Commonly used applications with restricted copyright (mp3, avi, mpeg, TrueType, Java, **Flash**, Codecs)